# Android apk size in appcelerator titanium

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

Developing a simple application. With a webview inside a window, loading a url. This simple app when built the apk size is 4.7MB. When installed in an android device this application takes around 11MB of space. I could shrink down the size by providing the

```
<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
</manifest>
```

But this also leaves me with 1.10 MB of size in HTC-Wildfire S, and 1.25MB of size in HTC-Desire HD.
For such a simple application i dont expect the application to be more than 500KB, considering that my artwork is around 200KB.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a good solution, will try and get back to you. Thanks again Samir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build your app into an apk, it includes the framework under which Titanium interprets your javascript code. There's going to be some overhead associated with that.

For your use case, it sounds like you would be much better off with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). It should be much more lightweight for your purposes.